# 2001 chevy impala has. No sound?

Tags: chevrolet, audio, impala

I've checked the fuses all are good. I have power to the amplifier. No codes are showing up! No broken wire on the passengers side!

Comment: Mute engaged? Volume set to off? Cable plugged in headphone socket?

Comment: I haven't seen a mute engage anywhere. Volume set to off? I'm not sure about that! Headset no!